# Is there a way to define custom tags in XML resources

Tags: android, xml

I would like to define something like this in the project res folder:

```xml
<custommap name="MyMap">
    <entry key="@string/key1" value="1">K1</entry >
    <entry key="@string/key2" value="2">K2</entry >
    <entry key="@string/key3" value="3">K3</entry >
    <entry key="@string/key4" value="4">K4</entry >
</custommap>
```

Is it somehow possible?. The example above does not pass compilation (I tried to insert it in arrays.xml).
If possible, how can it be accessed from the java code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android List of values with key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146195/android-list-of-values-with-key)

Comment: Yes, List of values with key is one possible use. But my question is broader. I gave just an example, did not mean it is the only use for it. If it were possible to define my own tags I would use it to store all kind of static data I now am defining as static variables.

Comment: Jeffrey, From the solution in the link you provided I understand everything can be achieved by using string arrays and integer and other kind of arrays. It is a nice workaround, but it is not as straightforward and elegant as to be able to write any tag you want with any attribute you want and then simply retrieve their values in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create your own xml file by right-clicking on the res folder and
   creating a new file under /xml folder.
2. Read your xml into ArrayList
   using the XMLParser as follows, by looking for the XML tags:

   ```
   public ArrayList<textElement> PrepareListFromXml(String cat)
   {
       textElement te;

       ArrayList<textElement> listItems = new ArrayList<textElement>();
       XmlResourceParser listXml = getResources().getXml(R.xml.<your resource name>);

       int eventType = -1;
       while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT)
       {
           if (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG)
           {                
               String strNode = listXml.getName();
               if (strNode.equals("entry"))
               {
                   te.setText(listXml.getAttributeValue(null, "key"));
                   listItems.add(te);
               }
           }

           try
           {
                eventType = listXml.next();
           }
           catch (XmlPullParserException e)
           {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
           }
           catch (IOException e)
           {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       return listItems;
   }
   ```

Comment: Great! Can you clarify some points, look at the pseudo-XML I posted above, at the beginning. Does getname() return "MyMap" or "custommap"? gettAttributeValue(null,"key") returns "@string/keyN" N depending on the entry? I guess use the same function to get the values 1,2,3,4. Then I should use a Map instead of ArrayList<> to be able to connect the elements with the key or value.  How do I get the K1, K2, K3, K4? How do you handle attributes of format myattr:mysubatttr="value"?

Comment: wiztrail, forget about it, I found a lot of info by googleing "XmlResourceParser" . I gave you the credit, thanks.