# Count element and Get attribute of items in resources

Tags: java, android

I have a resource file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <IDs name="IDs">
        <item type="id" name="bt_A"/>
        <item type="id" name="bt_B"/>
        <item type="id" name="bt_C"/>
        <item type="id" name="bt_D"/>
    </IDs>
</resources>
```

How can I count number of items in IDs. That means the result will be 4.

How can I get every **name** of item by loop. I can access R.id.bt_A, R.id.bt_B... But I can not imagine how get all **name** by loop. Something likes this (this code cannot run, just illustration):

```
for(int i=0; i<R.IDs.count; i++){
   Button bt = new Button(getBaseContext());
   bt.setId(R.IDs[i]);
}
```

I don't want to make one more static array to store all id again. I just want to use all id from my resource.

EDIT QUESTION
If my resource file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="length">4</integer>
    <item type="id" name="bt_1"/>
    <item type="id" name="bt_2"/>
    <item type="id" name="bt_3"/>
    <item type="id" name="bt_4"/>
    <string name="label_1">Ok</string>
    <string name="label_2">Cancel</string>
    <string name="label_3">Exit</string>
    <string name="label_4">Stop</string>
</resources>
```

I can get id by follows, but cannot get string value! How can I do?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GridLayout root = new GridLayout(getBaseContext());
        root.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        root.setRowCount(2);
        root.setColumnCount(2);

        int count = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.length);
        int[] ids = new int[count];
        String[] labels = new String[count];
        for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            ids[i] = getResources().getIdentifier("bt_" + (i+1), "id", getPackageName());
            labels[i] = getResources().getString(getResources().getIdentifier("label_"+(i+1),"string", getPackageName()));//Wrong, just trace true/false on button
        }
        Log.d("IDs", ids.toString());
        for(int i=0; i<count;i++){
            Button bt = new Button(getBaseContext());
            bt.setId(ids[i]);
            bt.setText(ids[i]);
            root.addView(bt, i);
        }

        setContentView(root);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to define custom tags in XML resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210593/is-there-a-way-to-define-custom-tags-in-xml-resources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no to generate arrays of ids automatically (android doesn't process internal ids, tried) though there is an alternative as per your requirement as

Declare length and id tags as

```
<integer name="length">4</integer>
<item type="id" name="bt_A"/>
<item type="id" name="bt_B"/>
<item type="id" name="bt_C"/>
<item type="id" name="bt_D"/>
```

then in java use the loop with character casting to ascii to get the values as

```
for(int i=65; i< 65+getResources().getInteger(R.integer.length); i++){
    Button bt = new Button(getBaseContext());
    bt.setId(getResources().getIdentifier("bt_"+(char)i,"id",getPackageName()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! If I wanna get attribute value of item element, how? `<item type="id" name="bt_A" value="Ok" />` The expected value is Ok

Comment: there is no such thing like [`value` attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id) , glad to help, happy coding~

Comment: I already edited my question, could you please answer it. I really need to load ID and Label from resource to buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="length">4</integer>
    <item type="id" name="bt_1"/>
    <item type="id" name="bt_2"/>
    <item type="id" name="bt_3"/>
    <item type="id" name="bt_4"/>

    <string-array name="labels">
        <item name="label_1">Ok</item>
        <item name="label_2">Cancel</item>
        <item name="label_3">Exit</item>
        <item name="label_4">Stop</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And Java code

```
package android.calculator;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;

public class ConstraintActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GridLayout root = new GridLayout(getBaseContext());
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0,0);
        root.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        root.setRowCount(2);
        root.setColumnCount(2);
        root.setAlignmentMode(GridLayout.ALIGN_MARGINS);
        root.setLayoutParams(params);

        int count = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.length);
        int[] ids = new int[count];
        String[] labels = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.labels);
        for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            ids[i] = getResources().getIdentifier("bt_" + (i+1), "id", getPackageName());
        }

        Log.d("IDs", ids.toString());
        for(int i=0; i<count;i++){
            Button bt = new Button(getBaseContext());
            bt.setId(ids[i]);
            bt.setText(labels[i]);
            root.addView(bt, i);
        }

        setContentView(root);
    }
}
```

## [image]

Comment: I am glad you solved the issue, though It would be great to add all requirements at once so the answerer has a chance to solve issue at once, modifying the question  should only be done to clarify the requirements though you can add new requirements although not ideal , happy coding